# Should <video> be used instead of <img>, to have a unselectable and undraggable background image like CSS "background", or is there a better way?

Tags: html, css

I was trying to have an image or maybe multiple images as a background and wanted it also it being simple to change it to a video as well, in case I want to.

However, with `<img>` I noticed an issue and with CSS, I couldn't reproduce the same that `<img>` did, so I came up with `<video>` and its attribute `poster` instead.

I'm wondering if that's a good idea. Below I explained what I tried and examples so you can see the difference between the `<img>` and CSS one.

---

I put an `<img>` as a background. The only issue is that it is selectable, however there are properties like `user-select`, but browsers like IE didn't support it.

Here is an example with `<img>`:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #090909;
}

div.background {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.background img {
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-width: none;
    max-height: none;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="background">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/sMzN1LP.png" draggable="false">
    </div>
    <div style="color: white;">Text</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hd6orszb/1/

Here, when you zoom out, the image stays in the screen, it's like `background-size: cover`. And when you zoom in, after zooming over 100%, it will zoom in the image as well. Which was okay, however the `<img>` can be dragged and selected and `user-select` doesn't work anywhere. The attribute "draggable" does, however even if you add `user-select: none;`, if you press CTRL + A, and drag the Text, in Chrome at least you can see the image being dragged as well. And I didn't wanted that.

---

So I used CSS, because this doesn't happen with the "background" property:

https://jsfiddle.net/5n6mtyb4

Now if you zoom out there and zoom in, there's nothing that keeps resizing it, like I did for `<img>`, so I added `background-size: cover`. But if you zoom in and out it will stay the same, but I wanted to keep the effect `<img>` did.

So I didn't had any idea, what else I could do. I think with `@media` it might be a bit hard because it's zooming, where anything can have a different size, I guess.

---

Other thing was using `<video>` with the `poster` attribute.

https://jsfiddle.net/5n6mtyb4/1/

Which was unselectable like the CSS one and behaves like `<img>` just unselectable as well. However I'm not sure if this is the ideal way to do it and if there could be any issues with that.

So I'm wondering, if there's a better way to do it, or if `<video>` is completely fine as an alternative to `<img>`.

Comment: You use the phrase "do it" twice, but it's not clear what "it" is. The only clue we have is something about it being selectable way at the start.

Comment: In other words, what problem does an element being "selectable" cause?

Comment: It being annoying and disturbing. Imagine if this technique gets used within a textbox or just some area to CTRL + A in, or the user mistakly causes all to be selected. Image would be copied within aswell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For IE9, you'll need to add `unselectable="on"` attribute it is like `user-select:none;`, and for drag you can add `draggable=flase` i find the background is the ideal, but video is fine also it has no problems with it using the poster.

**Edit Nov 20:** you can make psuedo element `before` Or `after` and they won't be selectable neither draggable, but you can't set `width` or `height` on the `url(img)`

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by adding these lines to CSS of your image:

```
 img {
 user-drag: none; 
 user-select: none;
 }
```

That should be the answer.

Comment: "user-drag" doesn't even seem to exist just like that

Comment: I tested it in the inspector tool and tried to Google for it.